# How to trigger an event when re-entering a page that has already been initialized in Angular Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I understand that Angular lifecycle hooks are useful for determining when a component is generated/destroyed such as `ngOnInit`, but once the component is generated, and a user leaves the page, and then comes back, the code that I need to run when entering the page isn't run because the existing component has already been initialized.

For example I have a music app, say I'm on an artist page:

`/tabs/(home:artist/:id)`

and I want to go to a release from that artist, I would route to:

`/tabs/(home:release/:id)`

When I first go to this page, the `ngOnInit` is run, therefore I can have a function that removes my loading screen once `ngOnInit` is triggered.

But say I go back to the artist page

`/tabs/(home:artist/:id)`

Then the release page still exists and hasn't been destroyed, so if I click to go back to that same release page, the `ngOnInit` is never run.

I am navigating using the following:
`private router: Router` from `@angular/router` in my constructor 
and switching pages using this method:

`this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/(home:release/${uid})')` (note: switched the ` for ' so I wouldn't break formatting in stackoverflow)

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I am using Ionic 4! Lifecycle hooks like `ionWillEnter()` were deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic has its own [lifecycles](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/)

Your case seems to be solved by using `ionViewWillEnter`

e.g.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
 //call ngOnInit or move methods in here
}
```

Comment: it is my understanding that these were deprecated in Ionic 4, I should have mentioned that!

Comment: yep this works, I'm not sure why it was error-ing out before. Thanks for having me look back in to this!